# Action for extended objects

Tags: general-relativity, action, dirac-delta-distributions, point-particles

Take a spacetime $M$, with some $k$-manifold embedding

$$X : \Sigma \to M$$

The image of $X$ represents some extended object (a $k$-brane as the string theory people say). If we only care about the dynamic of $X$, we can simply write its action using, say, the Nambu-Goto action :

$$S[X ; U] = \int_{X^{-1}(U)} d\mu[X_*g]$$

which is the volume of the induced metric (ie the pushforward of $g$ by $X$), or in the usual coordinates,

$$S[X ; U] = \int_U \sqrt{\det(g_{\mu\nu}(X(\sigma)) \partial_a X^\mu(\sigma) \partial_b X^\nu(\sigma) )} d^k\sigma$$

But if we want to consider the metric tensor as being itself dynamic (for instance if we're interested in the Nambu-Goto action to treat idealized topological defects, point particles, thin-shell spacetimes, etc), or if we want to couple it to another more traditional field (ie a charged point particle for instance), we generally want everything to be written in terms of an integral over the target space. But how to do this?

The various ways I tried to achieve this are :

**The naive way**

Simply add the two actions together :

\begin{equation}
S[X,g] = \int_M R_g d\mu[g] + \int_\Sigma d\mu[X_* g]
\end{equation}

Pros : Somewhat accurate, up to issues that I'll get into later regarding the class of $g$

Cons : Not useful to actually get the Euler-Lagrange equation

**The physicist way**

When done in physics papers, it's usually represented as

\begin{equation}
S[X, g ; U] = \int_U R_g + \left[\int_{X^{-1}(U)} \delta(x - X(\sigma)) \sqrt{\det(g_{\mu\nu}(x) \partial_a X^\mu(\sigma) \partial_b X^\nu(\sigma) )} d^k\sigma\right] d^n x
\end{equation}

This lets people use the variation of the metric tensor directly, and gives out the appropriate stress-energy tensor $T \approx m\delta(x(\tau))$ for point particles.

Pros : Good enough for calculations

Cons : Not terribly rigorous regarding the use of distributions

**De Rham currents**

The common way to deal with distributions on manifolds is the use of currents, which are linear functionals on $k$-forms with compact support. If we take the measure form $\omega = \sqrt{-g} \bigwedge dx_i$ and the integration current $[U]$. The Nambu-Goto action should be, I believe

\begin{equation}
S[X,g; U] = \langle X_* [U], \omega[g] \rangle
\end{equation}

with $X_* [U]$ the pushforward of the integration over $U$ by $X$. This is indeed equal to $\langle [U], X^* \omega[g] \rangle$ via the properties of currents, which I think is the original Nambu-Goto action. As everything is linear, I think the action should be something like

\begin{equation}
S[X,g; U] = \langle [U], R_g \omega[g] + X^* \omega[g] \rangle
\end{equation}

Pros : Somewhat rigorous, but see cons

Cons : The Euler-Lagrange equation of this quantity doesn't seem trivial to compute (I'm not quite sure how the fundamental lemma of variational calculus would crop up here). Also by the [Geroch-Traschen theorem](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.36.1017), $R$ can't be a smooth $0$-form (or even a distribution, depending on the brane), and so shouldn't be on this side

**Generalized functions**

To work with algebras of distributions, one can use a class of generalized functions (Colombeau generalized functions or asymptotic generalized functions), so that the metric, Riemann tensor and stress-energy tensor can all be expressed as generalized functions that are allowed to be singular.

Pros : All of that

Cons : It's not evident how the action should be written down for a distribution-valued action, or how the variation would work. Also, for physical reasonableness, the standard part of any measurable quantity should exist, and I don't know if that is guaranteed in any reasonable case.

Is there any method to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that *the naive, physicist, and de Rham way are all equivalent*. Specifically the de Rham way is defined precisely so that it is the "physicist" way when expressed in terms of a specific coordinate system (atlas). (I believe something is up with your volume forms in the "physicist way" in the version of your post I see.) The physicist way should reduce to the naive way once you integrate out the delta function. Coordinate-free expressions may make certain algebraic identities clearer and connect them to more general mathematical structures, but that simply *does not make them more rigorous*. "Rigorous" does not mean "the way a pure mathematician would prefer to express it".

The problem is, as you have noted, that by using these actions you do not get a meaningful classical field theory. Thus, you can understand it as an action for a quantum field theory, or as an action for a classical effective field theory, where in both cases the divergences are handled by some sort of regularization/renormalization procedure. In fact, the latter has been done in the case of classical post-Newtonian dynamics of compact objects, where it is technically simpler to work with effective point-particle actions along with covariant regularization procedures such as zeta-function, Hadamard, or dimensional regularization. (See e.g. the Living Review [*Gravitational Radiation from Post-Newtonian Sources and Inspiralling Compact Binaries* by Luc Blanchet](https://link.springer.com/article/10.12942/lrr-2014-2).)